# Procedure for Reply on MetaData rejected

Tags: ios, app-store, metadata, app-store-connect

How to reply for MetaData Rejected app in iTunes Connect. Submission from app store getting rejected due to insufficient metadata

Answer (score 1):

You can reply in "Resolution Center". Your response should be to the point. After that your app status will be moved to "In Review".

Answer (score 0):

If we did single mistake on this we have to wait more than a week and it added into beginning of the queue. Do not click “Submit for Review” after getting a Metadata Rejection

http://www.iosappsdevelopment.com/2015/06/metadata-rejected-from-itunes-connect.html

http://www.brynbodayle.com/an-easy-mistake-with-itunes-connect-metadata-rejections/